# como forçar download de arquivo kmz com php

Tags: php, download

estou tendo dificuldade para forçar um download de um arquivo tipo kmz (arquivo do google earth), faz-se o download porém o arquivo fica corrompido, alguém pode me ajudar?

```
$filename = "../kmz/".$_GET['id'];
        $filename = realpath($filename);

        $file_extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($filename,"."),1));


        if (!file_exists($filename)) {
            die("NO FILE HERE");
        }
        header("Pragma: public");
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Cache-Control: private",false);
        header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($filename)."\";");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header("Content-Length: ".@filesize($filename));
        set_time_limit(0);
        @readfile("$filename") or die("File not found.");
```

Comment: vc está fechando a tag do php(`?>`) ?

Comment: sim, esta funcionando com outros tipos de arquivo com pdf, jpg , rar e outos porem kmz nao funciona

Comment: Tente remover ela se possível, as vezes são adicionado caracteres a mais com a tag de fechamento que acabam 'corrompendo' o arquivo.

Comment: remover tag de fechamento?

Comment: Sim, tem html depois da tag de fechamento?

Comment: tem nao, é somente esse trecho de codigo e com as tags de abertura e fechamento do php

Comment: acredito q o arquivo seja de extensão desconhecida

Comment: já tentei usar Content-Type: unknown/unknown também não funcionou

Answer (score 0):

Coloque isso no seu arquivo .htaccess: 
**AddType application/octet-stream .kmz**

depois para fazer o download, é só criar um link ou ir na URL apontando direto para seu arquivo. Ex: http://www.example.com/link.kmz

Comment: onde encontro esse arquivo .htaccess?

Comment: Caso o arquivo .htaccess não exista, você deve cria-lo dentro da pasta onde está a página de acesso do site. (Ex: www/index.php - www/.htaccess)

Comment: o arquivo deverá conter este codigo?

AddType application/octet-stream .kmz
<Files 403.shtml> 
order allow,deny 
allow from all 
</Files>